# Centralized PulseAudio setup

Tags: networking, audio, home-networking, pulse-audio

I want to do a setup, so that all my computers and TV use one audio system. Like this:

[image]

Where media server is connected to acoustics and TV is connected through sound-card input and other systems use PulseAudio to access acoustics through network. Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partially – easy with Linux clients, tricky with Windows.

---

With Linux clients this is simple – just set `$PULSE_SERVER` to the media server's address and copy the `~/.pulse_cookie` authentication file.

```
PULSE_SERVER=tcp:mediaserver.home tcp6:mediaserver.home
```

Of course, make sure PulseAudio on the media server has the required modules loaded; most of them can be enabled via `paprefs`, or you could load them via `~/.pulse/default.pa` on the media server:

```
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
# required:
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp
# needed if you use WinESD:
load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
# optional, might be useful if you use Avahi:
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

---

There is no PulseAudio client for Windows yet, although one could use the ***very old*** [WinESD](http://dork.clingman.org:8080/winesd/) driver and Pulse's *ESounD* compatibility module, or the [`linco`](http://liveincode.rm.pp.ru/) tool as described in [this blog post](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2228/); here is a simplified version with `plink` from [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) in place of Cygwin:

```
linco -B 16 -C 2 -R 44100 | plink user@mediaserver "pacat --playback"
```

If you use iTunes, you could run [Shairport](https://github.com/albertz/shairport) on the media server, which will make it show up on iTunes as an AirPort.

(In fact, using Shairport with PulseAudio clients (via `module-raop-discover` + `module-raop-sink`) might use less bandwidth than the uncompressed Pulse protocol, but unfortunately there are some incompatibilities preventing this from working.)

Comment: I knew, that this is possible with Linux and my concern was chiefly about Windows. Thanks for suggestion, I'll try it.

Comment: @Shark: I also found [this article](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2228/) suggesting the use of `linco`. See my updated post.

Comment: Actually there has been a Windows Pulseaudio client/server for quite some time now. Just download it and run the pulseaudio.exe, then set PULSE_SERVER=ipaddress-of-windows. Personally, I'm searching for how to set this permanently.

Comment: @airtonix: A version more recent than 1.1?

Comment: @grawity nope, that's the version I'm using. On my ubuntu 13.10 desktop, I just edit `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, uncomment `default-server`, set it to the ip address of my windows laptop and launch `pulseaudio.exe` on my windows laptop. With synergy this ends up being very nice.

Comment: how is the latency with all that? Because I think pulse audio path introduces a delay..

Comment: @nass: No idea, but surely it won't be greater than the _network_-induced delay?

Comment: WinESD, linco, and gleamynode.net links are all dead.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the latest pulse audio release from http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/ (latest is v1.1 at time of writing).
2. unpack to somewhere you want. example: `c:\pulse\`
3. open `c:\pulse\etc\default.pa`
4. make sure you have something similar to :

   - `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=0.0.0.0 auth-anonymous=1`
   - `set-default-sink output`
5. On your linux machine(s), open `/etc/pulse/client.conf` (you could possibly do the same with `~/.pulse/client.conf`), make sure `default-server` is uncommented and set to the ip address of your windows machine (one you want to receive audio on)
6. restart pulseaudio on the linux machine(s), ubuntu: `pulseaudio -k`, for other distros I imagine you'd restart the server like you do any other `sudo service pulseaudio restart`.
7. On your windows machine, launch `pulseaudio.exe`. This should open a simple terminal with a few warnings (nothing to worry about from my experience).
8. On your Linux machine(s), launch something that plays sound.

Comment: Hey that `listen=127.0.0.1` worked perfect with `load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp ...` shown at [Simple Protocol Player](kaytat.com/blog/?page_id=301) for getting sound out of a chroot into Android via Pulse *magic*... next up is `SonicPi` on Android for mobile scripted musical composition. Thanks to @airtonix my tests'll be a bit more secure.